# How to get the console log from Chrome with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, console

I'm trying to get the console log, however, at the moment that I'm debugging, I can see that the instructions do not enter inside for sentence.

Here's my code:

```java
public void waitOffer() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 6);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webDriver.findElement(btnPreviewAd)));
    WebElement boton = webDriver.findElement(btnPreviewAd);
    boton.click();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/juan/Documents/Auto/SeleniumProject/resource/chromedriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);

    analyzeLog();
}

public void analyzeLog() throws InterruptedException {
    boolean flag;
    System.out.println("Hola probando");
    LogEntries logEntries = webDriver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) { //HERE MY PROBLEM, THIS FOR DO NOT ENTER INSIDE IN EXECUTION
        System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like there are no log entries in `logEntries` the length of that variable is 0. What are you expecting to see in the log?

Comment: In the site this is visible in the console:  [hugeAd] Template: NonEndemic
Chrysler_global.js:830 [hugeAd] Offer: emp_ca_apr
Chrysler_global.js:830 [hugeAd] Offer type: emp_ca_apr. I hope to read the log and if the label [hugeAd] is visible, I want to take a screenshot